# Spring batch dynamic execution flow

Tags: spring-batch

I'm working on a requirement that defines a job/execution unit as a list of ordered steps which are themselves defined as a list of ordered substeps/phases. This job can be started beginning at any of the first-level steps, potentially ignoring the N-th first steps (and their substeps/phases).

What would be the best strategy for implementing this with spring batch ?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to programmatically branching job execution (eg. skip step) is to use a [JobExecutionDecider](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/job/flow/JobExecutionDecider.html).

Comment: Hi and thanks for the answer. JobExecutionDecider is an option but how to know what is the index of the current job and if it is to be skipped ? I think we need some external reference that gives the index of a given job.

Comment: I think that informations are unrelated to SB but are specific information of your domain